# How to minimize the GCP cloud SQL billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am using Google Cloud Platform (Free Tier) for testing my application. I am using Cloud SQL and my DB size is 1 GB (Images). I am just testing the app so the number of users is only 1. The max time I spent is less than 2 hours per day (120 minutes max). But when I observe the billing, it says that I spent around Rs. 4000 (Indian Rupees-4K) per month.

Details: DB standard Intel N1 1 VCPU running in Mumbai (with 30% promotional discount).

How can I reduce the billing amount?

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud SQL instances basically charged on hourly basis. If you are using it for testing purpose alone, then it is better to stop the instance once you are done with the work and start it whenever you need. By doing this you can avoid getting charged for non-usage period and you pay only for the data storage alone.

Refer this pricing [chart](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/pricing) for Cloud SQL and refer [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/start-stop-restart-instance) one for start-stop-restart instances.

Comment: Thank you. I will go through the document.